# Format Date in Xpath

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, xpath, sharepoint-designer

I am editing the dispform.aspx in SharePoint Designer 2010, as to not show the created by fields in the announcement lists.
I notice that the expire ([Expires]) date field is off.
Example:

I have an expire date of `2/3/2012` but shows as `2012-02-03T04:00:00Z`

`<xsl:with-param name="dateValue" select="@Expires" />`

Comment: How is it "off"? That looks correct to me. Are you saying that you would prefer a `m/d/yyyy/` format?

Comment: I want it in the format `2/3/2012`.

Comment: I found a [this](http://autosponge.wordpress.com/2008/05/09/ddwrt-formatdate-and-formatdatetime/) web site, so I entered it as `<xsl:with-param name="dateValue" select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@Expires), 1033, 1)" />`, but it displays the same.

Comment: I'm assuming you're limited to XSLT/XPath 1.0, or can you use 2.0?

Comment: The page is configured for 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, XSLT/XPath 1.0 have no date manipulation functions (unless you count something like [EXSLT's "Dates and Times" function](http://www.exslt.org/date/), which I try not to, as these extension functions aren't always present).

If the source and result formats are going to remain fixed, you can do some basic (although ugly) string composition to accomplish what you want. In particular, this XPath:

```
concat(
  format-number(substring(., 6, 2), '0'),
  '/',
  format-number(substring(., 9, 2), '0'),
  '/',
  substring(., 1, 4)
)
```

...should do the trick.

**When this XSLT-based verification:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:value-of
       select="concat(
                 format-number(substring(., 6, 2), '0'),
                 '/',
                 format-number(substring(., 9, 2), '0'),
                 '/',
                 substring(., 1, 4)
               )" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied against this proposed XML:**

```
<t>2012-02-03T04:00:00Z</t>
```

**...the wanted result is produced:**

```
2/3/2012
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a bit of a noob with XSL, but where would I put the field @Expires in your code?

Comment: It can be placed at the very top, right above the first `<xsl:template>` declaration.

Comment: Tried to copy that into SharePoint Designer, but it didn't like it, so i just substituted the periods (.) with my field and it worked. THANKS! `<xsl:value-of select="concat(
                       format-number(substring(@Expires, 6, 2), '0'),
                       '/',
                       format-number(substring(@Expires, 9, 2), '0'),
                       '/',
                       substring(@Expires, 1, 4)
                     )" />
`